# Como posicionar dois selects dentro de uma mesma div?

Tags: html, css, html5, twitter-bootstrap, flat-ui

Preciso colocar dois `selects` dentro de uma mesma `div`, um alinhado à esquerda, e o outro à direita.

Já tentei usar CSS criando uma classe pra aplicar em cada `select`, mas não funcionou:

```
select.left {
  text-align: left;
}

select.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Estou usando o [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) + [`Flat-ui`](http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/), então já criei o exemplo verificável abaixo e o <kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gustavox/bbuxtLkk/2/)</kbd> com estas bibliotecas:

```html
 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/docs/assets/js/application.js"></script>
<link href="http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/dist/css/flat-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/dist/js/flat-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md-8">
    <label class="control-label" for="cest"> Estado: 
        <br/>
        <select name="Test" id="cest" class="select select-primary select-exemploa right" data-toggle="select"></select>
    </label>
    <label class="control-label" for="Ccid"> Cidade:
        <br/>
        <select class="select select-primary select-exemploa left"  name="Tcid" id="Ccid" data-toggle="select"></select>
    </label>
</div>
```

Nota: eles tem que ficar na mesma `div` porque senão o script que popula os `selects` não acha o da cidade depois que escolheu o estado. Neste link tem um [fiddle com o plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/sgecadth/16/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar colunas `<div class="col-md-6">` dentro das colunas.

Não coloque os `selects` dentro dos `labels`.

Use a classe `form-control` nos `selects`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/docs/assets/js/application.js"></script>
<link href="http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/dist/css/flat-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/dist/js/flat-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="content">
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 col-md-12 col-md-12 col-md-12">
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <label class="control-label" for="cest"> Estado:</label>
     <select name="Test" id="cest" class="select select-primary select-exemploa form-control" data-toggle="select">
          </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <label class="control-label" for="Ccid"> Cidade:</label>
          <select class="select select-primary select-exemploa form-control"  name="Tcid" id="Ccid" data-toggle="select">
          </select>
      
    </div>
 </div>
  </div></div>
```

> Nota: eles tem que ficar na mesma `div` porque senão o *script* que popula os `selects` não acha o da cidade depois que escolheu o estado.

HTML não é um código estático e sua marcação será alterada quase que sempre, por isso não crie *scripts* que "navegue" entre as tags, pra isso existem os `ids`.

Comment: Então, mas não posso dividir em duas colunas, porque senão o plugin não popula o segundo select... aqui tem um [fiddle com o plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/sgecadth/16/), dá uma olhada...

Comment: Então, eu to usando classe porque uso dois conjuntos desses `selects`. Se fosse apenas um, daria pra usar por `id`sem problema, mas com dois tem que ser por classe, só que aí não posso usar uma `div` pra cada (o que seria o ideal btw, até mesmo pela responsividade)... Mais pra frente to pensando em usar um outro tipo (de autocomplete), mas por enquanto vai ter que ser este mesmo... Será que não tem nenhum jeito? Valeu.

Comment: @gustavox você dispõe do jQuery, basta fazer uso: http://jsfiddle.net/sgecadth/19/

Comment: Na verdade até o seu código está funcionando corretamente: http://jsfiddle.net/sgecadth/21/ só que você colocou-o dentro do `window.load` e o JSFiddle já estava fazendo isso.

Comment: É isso! Ainda tirei o `#Cform`, e deixei apenas `$('.classdivcolb')` por sugestão da ID e ficou perfeito. Valeu!